# Tengo dudas con el uso de react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Buenas amigos estoy usando la api de youtube para obtener los videos, el problema consiste en que estoy usando react-router, tengo mi componente Show en donde tengo mi tag  que va a llamar a mi componente Reproductive pero pasa un problema porque mi componente reproductive quiero que me lleguen datos (titulo del video,  x valor ) pero la manera de enviarle datos es por medios de las props, pero no lo puedo enviar de esa forma porque no quiero que se me muestro el video si no hasta que llame a mi ruta.

Dejare los componentes en donde tengo las dudas ojala puedan ayudarme por favor no he encontrada un ayuda clara con esto

[image: Componente Show es donde se encuentra nuestro tag <link>]

[image: Componente Reproductive, es a quien llamo con react-router y quien quiero que reciba mis datos pero no logro como]

Ya logro obtener el video correspondiente, lo que me falta es enviarle datos para obtener el nombre del video y otra lista de video que son los relacionados. Ayuda por favor

Comment: Hola Manuel, tal vez sería más conveniente que publicaras aquí un ejemplo [mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) que ilustre tu problema, para que las personas que puedan ayudarte puedan tener todo el panorama sin tener que abandonar tu pregunta.

Comment: Ok amigo esta bien, gracias editare la pregunta y pondre los componentes en donde tengo las dudas

Comment: No pongas imágenes con código, pon siempre el texto. Es más cómodo para todos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existen diferentes soluciones, dependiendo de como estés manejando el estado de tu app. La más común es implementar la arquitectura que propone Facebook, [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/), existen numerosas librerías que te harán más sencillo el trabajo. Otra opción (y la que personalmente más me está convenciendo) es utilizar ***observables***, [Mobx](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx) es una librería que facilita mucho la tarea. Como ultima opción (y no muy recomendable) podrías almacenar las propiedades que necesites 'compartir' en variables globales y así estarán disponibles donde las necesites.

Comment: observables, es correcto, tambien con el uso de los hooks pero con el uso de un bind de los arreglos que necesitas llamar creo que basta ya que cuando usas el bind desde un constructor se llama a la funcion this que hace una instacia desde el mismo elemento o clase que se esta usando, yo ahorita estoy viendo algunas conference que hablan sobre eso tambien recuerda el uso de las funciones o metodos que llaman a cada componente desde que es usado hasta que finaliza es decir componentWillMount() componentDidMount().  el cycle life de cada component